# Spring - Java configuration @Bean parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I've just updated from Spring 3.1.1 to 3.2.6

With 3.1 the following code worked well:

```
@Bean(name = DEMO_DS)
public JndiObjectFactoryBean demoDataSource()
{
    JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    factory.setJndiName(JDBC_DEMO_DS);
    factory.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = DEMO_SESSION_FACTORY)
public SqlSessionFactoryBean demoSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier(DEMO_DS) DataSource dataSource)
{
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("demo/config.xml"));

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

However with the uprgraded version I get the following exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=DemoDataSource)}

I have multiple DataSources hence the @Qualifier is a need.

Thanks.

Edit:

It seems that this solves the problem:

```
public DataSource dataSourceFactory() {
    try
    {
        return (DataSource) demoDataSource().getObject();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

...

sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceFactory());
```

However I don't think it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your need rewrite your configuration a little. If you don't really need the datasource injected you can do something like this.

```
@Bean(name = DEMO_DS)
public JndiObjectFactoryBean demoDataSource() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    factory.setJndiName(JDBC_DEMO_DS);
    factory.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = DEMO_SESSION_FACTORY)
public SqlSessionFactoryBean demoSqlSessionFactory() {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(demoDataSource().getObject());
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("demo/config.xml"));
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

If you need to have a datasource injected you might want to switch to using a `JndiLocatorDelegate` to do the lookup instead of a `JndiObjectFactoryBean`.

```
@Bean(name = DEMO_DS)
public DataSource demoDataSource() throws NamingException {
    return JndiLocatorDelegate.createDefaultResourceRefLocator().lookup(JDBC_DEMO_DS, DataSource.class);
}
```

This gives you a `DataSource` directly instead of a `FactoryBean<Object>` (which is what the `JndiObjctFactoryBean` is) what probably is the source of the problem.

Or (in theory) you should also be able to use a `@Value` annotation on a property in your config class. Instead of a `@Value` a normal `@Resource` should also do the trick (that can also delegate a call to JNDI for a lookup).

```
public class MyConfig {

    @Value("${" + JDBC_DEMO_DS + "}")
    private DataSource demoDs;

}
```

With `@Resource`

```
public class MyConfig {

    @Resource(mappedName=JDBC_DEMO_DS)
    private DataSource demoDs;

}
```

And you can then simply reference it in your configuration method.

```
@Bean(name = DEMO_SESSION_FACTORY)
public SqlSessionFactoryBean demoSqlSessionFactory() {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(demoDs);
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("demo/config.xml"));
    return sessionFactory;
}
```